# How do I conditionally format a header cell for ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to format all columns that contain numbers only as right-aligned. The cell text was simple, but how can I format the header text? My table will contain columns of strings and columns of numbers and I'm trying to set all column contents and headers of those number columns to right-align.

I have tried to set a global style, but that affects the whole grid (all left-aligned or all right-aligned). I have also tried to create a custom header component but didn't have much success with that either. I also tried to set the 'flex-direction: row' but I can't high enough up the DOM to access the correct element.

***Here is an example***: https://plnkr.co/edit/QAqGaRXXpt1KUYdrnWU7?p=preview

*And the code from the plnkr so I can post the question:*

**main.js**

```
var columnDefs = [
  {
    headerName: "Athlete", 
    field: "athlete", 
    width: 180, 
  },
  {
    headerName: "Age (Should be aligned right)",
    field: "age",
    width: 250,
    cellStyle: {'text-align': 'right'}
  }
];

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: null,
    suppressMenuHide: true,
    defaultColDef: {
      width: 100,
      filter: true
    }
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    // do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep the example self contained.
    // you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else to do your HTTP calls.
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/master/packages/ag-grid-docs/src/olympicWinnersSmall.json');
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var httpResult = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            gridOptions.api.setRowData(httpResult);
        }
    };
});
```

**style.css**

```
.customHeaderMenuButton {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    background-color: green;
}

.customHeaderLabel {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 3px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.active {
    color: cornflowerblue;
}

.rightAligned {
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: red;
}
```

The "Age" header text should be right-aligned, and possibly display the filter menu on the left side so it looks neater with the rest of the column text.

Comment: would you know beforehand which columns are numbers and which columns are strings?

Comment: @Aldric Yes, the data type for each column won't change.

Comment: then you should be able to set the numeric columns for the numeric col defs, you can refer to this link https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#numeric-columns